# Is it possible to compute a HMAC in .NET using a key that has been persisted as a CNGkey object?

Tags: c#, .net, cryptography, hmac, cng

Is it possible to compute a HMAC in .NET using a key that has been persisted as a [CNGkey](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.cngkey?view=net-8.0) object?

There are a variety of encryption algorithms supported in .NET and .NET Framework that support this - such as [AESCng](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.aescng.-ctor?view=net-8.0#system-security-cryptography-aescng-ctor(system-string)); however, from what I can see, [all HMAC constructors require the key value to be inputted into the HMAC constructor as a raw byte array (as opposed to the name of the persisted key to be used in the case of AES)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.hmacsha3_256.-ctor?view=net-8.0#system-security-cryptography-hmacsha3-256-ctor(system-byte())).

Comment: Did you try to use Export method? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.cngkey.export?view=net-8.0#system-security-cryptography-cngkey-export(system-security-cryptography-cngkeyblobformat)